# Behat config on multisite

Tags: 8, testing

I have a drupal8 multisite with no default site settings. So my folder structure looks like:

```
sites/Asite/settings.php
sites/Bsite/settings.php
```

With a separate database connection in them and none in the default directory.
I've setup a behat.yml with the following:

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
      base_url: http://172.24.0.13:80
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
      api_driver: 'drupal'
      drush:
        alias: 'local'
      drupal:
        drupal_root: '/srv/web'
```

I have added

```
 "behat/behat": "3.3",
  "behat/mink": "^1.7",
  "behat/mink-extension": "^2.3",
  "drupal/drupal-extension": "^4.0",
```

to my composer.json file.
If i place my behat.yml file in the root i'm getting an error:

```
In Database.php line 361:

  The specified database connection is not defined: default
```

Where and how can i configure my behat file so i can run my test against each subsite.

Comment: AFAIK you have to have one behat.yml for each multisite instance.

Comment: And where should be placed?

Comment: If i place the behat.yml under 
sites/Asite/
then when running behat -dl it will not recognize any steps.

Comment: You place them all in the same directory where you'd normally place the default `behat.yml` but name them differently and then start tests one after the other, pointing to a certain Behat file: `behat --config behat-site-foo.yml` and then `behat --config behat-site-bar.yml` and so on. And every `behat-site-NAME.yml` points to a different base URL.

Comment: I have managed to get past the database connection error but no is giving me a cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)

Comment: Which is a different question. I don't know when this error occurs. When starting the tests? When executing a specific scenario? Have you checked your site is up at all? Here's a setup that works https://github.com/leymannx/drupal-circleci-behat/blob/develop/tests/behat/behat.yml. Leave out the Selenium part if you don't have Selenium.

Comment: The setup in the link you've sent was for multi-site setup?